# Max safe capacitor voltage

Tags: capacitor

**I Have spent hours trying to figure out how to complete the maximum safe working voltage and cannot match the answer below.**

- **I can find the total capacitance by using the series capacitor formula.**

Thats easy .

**I also know the total current must be found using the formula I = V/Xc. Xc being reactance**

**My attempt to find the total safe working voltage:**

As they all have the same current going through them the current stays the safe therefore. **I** = **Va/Xca**    = **Vb/Xcb**     = **Vc/Xcc**
**I have researched forums after forums and this is as far as I can get.

Please dont report me as this is as far as I can go and I have tried my best. **I feel like I deserve the derivation now.**
Cheers.

[image]**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You know that all capacitors must contain the same charge. As such you need to find out which capacitor holds the least amount of charge at its rated voltage using the standard formula \$Q = CV\$. That becomes your **MAX** Charge.

Once you know that you can figure out the voltage across the other two capacitors at that charge. Add those up and you have the max safe voltage for the series combination.

[image]

Comment: You couldn't have said it any clearer. I get it now. The capacitors charge with the least amount of charge = the charge across the other two capacitors.